# Securely Storing Database Password

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, encryption, sql-server-ce

I'd like to randomly generate an encryption key and password for an SQL Server CE database when it's created, and then save the key in some secure way that would allow the program to open a connection, but not be easily reachable by potential attackers.

I'm working on an offline WPF application that stores certain user and setting information in a local database.

My current implementation is to have one "Device Password" that the user sets up which is used as the encryption key for the generated SQL Server CE database password. The base64 encrypted database password is then saved in a simple .txt settings file. When the application starts up, the user enters the Device Password and that string is used as the decryption key for the saved password. If the resulting string is able to open a connection to the database, the password was correct and the program is opened with full access.

What I'm trying to do now is modify the system to allow multiple users with specific Username/Password credentials to open the program and access the database with varying levels of privilege. The way that I'm trying to achieve this is by handling the user authentication separately, and opening the database regardless of the credentials to load some basic application info.

Below is roughly my current implementation:

```
        var candidateDBPwd = DecryptDatabasePassword(passwordBox.Password, Settings.Instance.EncryptedDatabasePassword);

        if (candidateDBPwd.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            // User's password didn't decrypt database password.
            return false;
        }

        if (File.Exists(Constants.DB_FILE))
        {
            // Normal operation: Try to open the database file to see that 
            // we've got the correct password.
            string databaseArguments = Constants.DB_ARGS_SECURE + candidateDBPwd;
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(databaseArguments))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException ex)
                {
                    // Failed to open the database: User's password must have been wrong!
                    return false;
                }
            }
```

I've spent the past few hours researching similar issues and am now beginning to wonder if it's possible. Consensus seems to state that storing passwords or connectionStrings in the App.config file is futile because if you encrypt the sections, you still need to store that key somewhere in code. Most of the existing SO threads on the issue seem to be several years out of date and it seems that that practice has deprecated. Is there some new respectable way to store a local database password? Or would you recommend a different approach to implementing the feature?

Comment: Some of the similar threads I've read and am referring to are the following:

[Dated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975377/encrypt-connection-string-in-non-asp-net-applications)

[Dated but providing good context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620028/data-encryption-and-key-management-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The Mobile Development Handbook has a couple of chapters dedicated to this non-trivial issue: http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft%C2%AE-Mobile-Development-Handbook-Wigley/dp/0735623589

Comment: It depends on how you publish your application. `App.config` could be encrypted during the first launch of your app, so it might be just ok four you.

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks for the referral, I'll probably need to get myself a copy. This handbook was published though in 2007, and is based on .NET 2.0. Should I take this as meaning that there haven't been many substantial developments related to the issue since then?

Comment: @VDohnal I'm not the one who builds the installers or works on publishing but I can speak to them about our process. Is there a way we could encrypt the `App.config` during install that would allow us to access the encryption key again if the program needed to rebuild the database?

Comment: @Blairinks Yes, and the discussion in the book is quite general anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you information here is the code snippet that can be used to encrypt certain sections of `app.config`. This is machine specific encryption and I think it is most simple and straightforward way to go.

I am using this  with Click-once app, so that the config sections are encrypted during the first launch of the app. It means, that it is unecrypted on the publish server, it is downloaded also unencrypted and it is encrypted right after the installation finishes and application is started.

So using this method you have to distribute your files unencrypted and they are enrypted only after the installation is completed. I suppose it can be achieved by running this code during install, it depends on how you plan to install your app.

Also you can use `UnprotectSection()` to unencrypt previously encrypted section.

```
static void EncryptConfig()
{
    // Encrypt config for ClickOnce deploys on first run
    // ClickOnce deploys config into 2 dirs, so the parent dir is traversed to encrypt all
    if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
    {
        // Get paths
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string exeName = Path.GetFileName(asm.Location);
        string configName = exeName + ".config";
        DirectoryInfo parentPath = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

        // Protect config files
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in parentPath.GetDirectories())
        {
            foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                if (fil.Name == configName)
                {
                    ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                    fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = fil.FullName;
                    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                    ProtectSection(config, "connectionStrings");
                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void ProtectSection(Configuration config, string sectionName)
{
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);
    if (section != null)
    {
        if (!section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
        {
            section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
        }
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
    }
    else
        Tools.LogWarning("Section {1} not found in {0}.",config.FilePath, sectionName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! A slightly modified version of this allowed me to do exactly what I've been trying to by being able to read and update the information without ever needing to store it in plain text. For those who may have no experience with this process like I did when I began my search, [Here's a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) of one way to access and save information in the App.config.

Answer (score -1):

You can store it in registry editor. You mention that your system is offline wpf application .

Comment: It is not exactly what I would call secure.